# How to separate my array into some parts in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord, discord.js, slice

I'm doing pagination in an embed and I wanted to split 4 elements from an array for each page. How do I do this? (to update when I click the button). Until then I have only the first step which is to get the first 4 elements, from the first page, with:

`.slice(0, 4)`

How do I get the next 4, and the next, and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to define:

- currentPage variable (set to 1 as default value)
- pageSize - how many items should be for one page
- countPages - for calculation, rounded in bigger side

I have written 3 methods

- `loadFirstPage()`
- `loadNextPage()`
- `loadPrevPage()`

```js
const input = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13];
let currentPage = 1;
let pageSize = 4;
const countPages = Math.ceil(input.length / pageSize);


function loadFirstPage() {
    currentPage = 1;
    return [...input].splice(0, pageSize)
}

function loadNextPage() {
    const nextPage = currentPage + 1;
    if (nextPage <= countPages) {
        currentPage = nextPage;
        const startIndex = currentPage * pageSize - pageSize;
        return [...input].splice(startIndex, pageSize)
    } else {
        currentPage = countPages;
        const startIndex = currentPage * pageSize - pageSize;
        return [...input].splice(startIndex, pageSize)
    }
}

function loadPrevPage() {
    const prevPage = currentPage - 1;
    if (prevPage >= 1) {
        currentPage = prevPage;
        const startIndex = currentPage * pageSize - pageSize;
        return [...input].splice(startIndex, pageSize)
    } else {
        currentPage = 1;
        const startIndex = currentPage * pageSize - pageSize;
        return [...input].splice(startIndex, pageSize)
    }
}

console.log('output data: ', loadFirstPage(), 'current page: ', currentPage);

console.log('output data: ', loadNextPage(), 'current page: ', currentPage);
console.log('output data: ', loadNextPage(), 'current page: ', currentPage);
console.log('output data: ', loadNextPage(), 'current page: ', currentPage);
console.log('output data: ', loadNextPage(), 'current page: ', currentPage);

console.log('output data: ', loadPrevPage(), 'current page: ', currentPage);
console.log('output data: ', loadPrevPage(), 'current page: ', currentPage);
console.log('output data: ', loadPrevPage(), 'current page: ', currentPage);
console.log('output data: ', loadPrevPage(), 'current page: ', currentPage);
```

Comment: Hello. I tried this solution on my pagination but splice is modifying the original array so it also alters the index. Using currentPage * pageSize - pageSize will jump 2 pages instead of just 1. From 1-4 to 9-12.

Comment: @user874737 as you can see I am using "[...input]". It is a new array