# Pagination next and previous for embed discord js

Tags: javascript, pagination, discord.js

I have an array that I need to divide into pages with each page showing 4 numbers. I need help on the Next and Previous page commands.

There's an answer about this before in here: [How to separate my array into some parts in discord.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71599029/how-to-separate-my-array-into-some-parts-in-discord-js), but I couldn't make it work. Using `splice` modifies the original array and rearranges the index so the formula there of `currentPage * pageSize - pageSize` for the next page start index isn't working properly.

Here are the variables for my pagination

```
let numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
let currentPage = 1;
let pageSize = 4;
const countPages = Math.ceil(input.length / pageSize);
```

Here's the code to show the initial page which shows **1, 2, 3, 4**

```
numberArray.splice(0, pageSize);
```

Here's the code for Next but this outputs **9, 10, 11, 12**.

```
const nextPage = currentPage + 1;
if (nextPage <= countPages) {
    currentPage = nextPage;
    const startIndex = currentPage * pageSize - pageSize;
    numberArray.splice(startIndex, pageSize)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `splice` as it modifies the original array. Although you already know this, you can run the following snippet and see how `splice` removed those four items from the original `array`:

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
let pageContent = array.splice(4, 4)

console.log('pageContent:', pageContent.toString())
console.log('array:', array.toString())
```

You could use `slice` instead that returns a new array:

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
let pageContent = array.slice(4, 8)

console.log('pageContent:', pageContent.toString())
console.log('array:', array.toString())
```

You could also create a class for this:

```js
class Paginator {
  constructor(array, pageSize) {
    this.array = array;
    this.pageSize = pageSize;
    this.currentPage = 1;
  }

  getPage() {
    const startIndex = (this.currentPage - 1) * this.pageSize;
    return this.array.slice(startIndex, startIndex + this.pageSize);
  }

  next() {
    if (this.currentPage * this.pageSize < this.array.length) {
      this.currentPage += 1;
    }
    return this.getPage();
  }

  previous() {
    if (this.currentPage > 1) {
      this.currentPage -= 1;
    }
    return this.getPage();
  }

  first() {
    this.currentPage = 1;
    return this.getPage();
  }

  last() {
    this.currentPage = Math.ceil(this.array.length / this.pageSize);
    return this.getPage();
  }
}

let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
let pageSize = 4
let paginator = new Paginator(array, pageSize)
console.log(`
  First: ${paginator.first()}
  Next: ${paginator.next()}
  Next: ${paginator.next()}
  Previous: ${paginator.previous()}
  Last: ${paginator.last()}
`)
```